# How to make Horizontal Bias limited by other view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one main guideline, that's going to be programatically adjusted. To that, I attached 'anchor' that's supposed to always center on aforementioned guideline. Then, further view is going to be attached to the anchor.

The problem is - how can I also add constraint, that'll change horizontal bias, so that view attached do anchor is held within the screen?

[image: Descriptive image]

Here's layout I've got that will not limit to screen bounds:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="148dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aasdasdasdadasdasda"
            tools:text="asdasadasdasddddddddddd" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="117dp">

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```